# sum of squared difference for list of lists with a single list elements

Tags: python, list, iterator, sum

I have the below two lists and am trying to get the sum of squared difference between the lists

```
list = [[20.20458675 17.14946271  2.78568516  5.8363439  14.00318441 11.96825089]
 [ 3.89675236  9.99523907 13.0328716  18.10551237 22.11318234 -0.30354959]]

primary = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

result = [x, y]

x is sum of squared difference of each element in list[1] and each element in primary (20.20458675 - 0)**2 + (17.14946271 - 1)**2 + .....
y is sum of squared difference of each element in list[2] and each element in primary (3.89675236 - 0)**2 + (9.99523907 - 1)**2 + ......
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
count = 0
for i in list:
    sum = 0
    count += 1
    for j in range(len(i)):
        sum += (i[j] - primary[j])**2
    result[count] = sum
```

I was ending up with a list index error, Any suggestions on how to go about this:

Comment: you get index error because i is an integer and it has no length attribute `for j in range(len(i)):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
arrList = np.array(lst) # Don't use 'list' as variable name
arrPri = np.array(primary)
x, y = np.sum((arrList-arrPri)**2, axis=1)
# x:
# array([408.22532574, 260.80514582,   7.76004181,  34.06291012,
#    196.08917362, 120.30252759])
# y:
# array([ 15.18467896,  80.91432593, 169.85574214, 327.80957818,
#    488.9928332 ,   1.69924153])
```

Comment: if you could add `np.sum((arrList-arrPri)**2,axis=1)` to your code it would be best

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my explanation was not right. I am looking to get the sum of all elements in x and sum of all elements in y in the above code you've mentioned to be stored in a list like this result = [sum(x) , sum(y)] ( I mean with the actual values)

Comment: @stackuser thats why i told him to add this code :). it gets the sum of the two arrays and puts in another array

Comment: That worked from Albin paul.

Thank you both of you!

Comment: @AlbinPaul Sry didn't see that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
listl= [[20.20458675 ,17.14946271 , 2.78568516 , 5.8363439 , 14.00318441 ,11.96825089]
, [ 3.89675236 , 9.99523907, 13.0328716 , 18.10551237, 22.11318234 ,-0.30354959]]

primary = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
for i in listl:
    print(sum(map(lambda x:(x[0]-x[1])**2,zip(primary,i))))
```

OUTPUT

```
1027.2451246961205
1084.4563999396066
```

Comment: how do I convert the my list to the listl shown here?

Comment: put commas in between elements in a list ?

Comment: yes, how do I convert that, is there a built in function?

Comment: I am asking this cause my list is not static

Comment: for now I just did np.array(lst) but it is giving me and error pointing at a space My lst does not have comma's as of now

Comment: yes , list should have commas . if it has more than two elements